# Ad delivery refresh rate

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page on my site where people watch live streams... I'm trying to update the advertising banners there through OpenX every ten minutes.

```
$('#ad_tag_top_left').html($('#ad_tag_top_left').html());
```

This isn't doing the job... I'm wondering if anyone's done this before or has any suggestions.  I've verified that `$('#ad_tag_top_left').html()` does indeed return the following code...

```
<!--//<![CDATA[
  document.MAX_ct0 ='INSERT_CLICKURL_HERE';

  var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://www.gamer-source.com/ad-server/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://www.gamer-source.com/ad-server/www/delivery/ajs.php');
  var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);

  if (!document.MAX_used)
    document.MAX_used = ',';

  document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
  document.write ("?zoneid=62");
  document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);

  if (document.MAX_used != ',')
    document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);

  document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
  document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));

  if (document.referrer)
    document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));

  if (document.context)
    document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));

  if ((typeof(document.MAX_ct0) != 'undefined') && (document.MAX_ct0.substring(0,4) == 'http')) {
    document.write ("&amp;ct0=" + escape(document.MAX_ct0));
  }

  if (document.mmm_fo) 
    document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");

  document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
//]]>-->
```

Could the comments be stopping it from executing even though it's within an HTML comment tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write) (used both in the above snippet and in the ad code referenced by it) will only work while the page is loading, so your code (which can't be used to execute JavaScript anyways) cannot work. The best solution in your case (*i.e.* if you cannot rewrite the script to use jQuery entirely) is to put the ad code inside an iframe:

```
<iframe
    src="ad_code.html"
    width="width of your banner"
    height="height of your banner"
    frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Then put this auto-refresh code inside the `ad_code.html` file in addition to the ad code:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload();
}, 600000);
</script>
```

Hopefully, the ad code (if an ad is clicked on) will open the sponsor's web page not in the iframe but in the containing window.

Answer (score 1):

OpenX offers the iFrame invocation code and it supports refresh natively.