# Javascript: rewriting messy code, CDATA, using anonymous-functions is faster?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I wanted to rewrite advertiser script as it looks like mess. And I don't understand what's the CDATA thing there means.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--<![CDATA[
    document.write(unescape('%3C')+'script id="ADNET.LT.starchat.lt.Pixel_VisaAplinka" src="'+location.protocol+'//s2.ad.adocean.pl/_'+(new Date()).getTime()+'/ad.js?id=W54MHZcb7Z4vrcQ10kJleC.24iQP2N39Uy9dCJXnEmb.A7/x='+screen.width+'/y='+screen.height+'" type="text/javascript"'+unescape('%3E%3C')+'/script'+unescape('%3E'));
//]]>--></script>
```

So I turned it in something like this, just I stuck on few things:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ad = document.createElement('script'); ad.type = 'text/javascript'; ad.async = true; ad.id = 'ADNET.LT.starchat.lt.Pixel_VisaAplinka'; ad.src = 'http://s2.ad.adocean.pl/' + new Date().getTime() + '/ad.js?id=W54MHZcb7Z4vrcQ10kJleC.24iQP2N39Uy9dCJXnEmb.A7/x=' + screen.width + '/y=' + screen.height;
</script>
```

Should I use the script within anonymous function? How is it different or better as I noticed everyone uses them now like Google Analytics script and others?

And one more thing, i need to insert the script object i created in ad variable in the document, but not in the head tag, but within the element where the script is, should I use some parent property?

Comment: Please ask each question individually. They're not connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the code in a self-executing anonymous function to hide your variables from other code.
This avoids polluting the global namespace.

You can simply append your new `<script>` element to the end of the body.

Comment: Oh, I believe it doesn't matter where I append it, right.. I thought maybe it will change the location where the banner from their script would appear.

Comment: If their script uses `document.write`, then I suspect that adding the script using `createElement` will break the page.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason advertiser tend to do stuff like that is to fake out ad-blockers.  They add a script to the page in strange ways so they won't be detected as ads, and therefore the ads will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Really quick... the CDATA stuff is in case the script is embedded in a strict XHTML document. The

If you add the script tag after the DOM is ready via JS, and it has document.write, then that is a failure. Different browsers do different things, but document.write is not allowed at that point in time, and I believe IE for example will blank the screen (maybe FF too).

At any rate, you don't know what is in the ad script so changing the semantics is bad -- they should do it. You might have something work today and fail tomorrow otherwise. (Even putting the ad in an iframe is a problem since all their referrals will be from your iframe, and faking the page it is in if often against terms, not to mention problematic if they were using window.location to scan your page for contextual content).

Answer (score 0):

If a third-party ad script depends on [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write)  (see Notes section of the linked document) at all, it is likely that you cannot "clean up" the code to conform to modern JavaScript coding standards because such code depends on that function's behavior of inserting the new HTML at the place where it is called (so that one can just copy/paste the ad code where it is wanted on the page).

The closest you could come is to [override the behavior of the `document.write` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231948/getscript-or-eval-in-specific-location) so that it stores ad code in a variable then inserts it into a container of your choice after the ad script is done (jQuery has a way to do the latter).

**Here's what I would do:** just put the ad code in an iframe if your ad network allows it if you need to "isolate" the ad code from your other JavaScript. Compare with my answer to [Ad delivery refresh rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252355/ad-delivery-refresh-rate).